# How would you parse a date (of any reasonable format) from a big chunk of text?

Tags: parsing, text

Trying to parse emails for flight information. I have ways to parse airline code, destination, flight number, etc... but am stuck on how to parse the date of the flight. Typically, flight confirmation emails from different airlines have multiple dates in a variety of formats.

Comment: Not enough information. What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: @DwayneTowell I'm trying to parse flight itinerary dates from flight confirmation emails. I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the correct date (in different formats) throughout a variety of different confirmation emails.

Answer (score 1):

For unstructured poorly formatted text I use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) interface to [Marpa, a general BNF parser](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html). Describe your input as BNF and Marpa pretty much does the rest.

Here is the [output](https://gist.github.com/rns/dcbcfb9bfe2e4e0e9494#file-output) of a [Marpa-based parser](https://gist.github.com/rns/dcbcfb9bfe2e4e0e9494#file-parser-pl) for rather diverse [PHP Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Hope this helps.